# How to get table column value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I write follow code to get one record from the table `webeehs`:

```
webeehs_result = Webeeh.find(:all, :conditions=>["webeeh_project_id=#{project_id}"])
```

Then I want to get one column value from this record, how could I do?
For example, the column name is `webeeh_date`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

first of all, never EVER write code like that. Building your own conditions as pure strings can leave you vulnerable to SQL injection exploits. If you must do conditions, then do it like this:

```
:conditions => ["webeeh_project_id = ?", project_id]
```

if you have a Project model, you should rename the `webeeh_project_id` column from your Webeeh model into `project_id` and have an association in your Project model like `has_many :webeehs`

Then, you won't need to call that find anymore, just do a `p = Project.find(id)` and then `p.webeehs` will return the webeehs you need.

the result will be an array which you can iterate through. And to get your `webeeh.webeeh_date` member, just call it like this:

```
result.each do |webeeh|
   date = webeeh.webeeh_date
end
```

Answer (score 2):

```
webeehs_result = Webeeh.findwebeeh_dates
```

is enough to get all columnn values.

For a different method and performance issues check the following: http://www.stopdropandrew.com/2010/01/28/finding-ids-fast-with-active-record.html

Answer (score 0):

webeeh_result will usually be an array of results for the database.

You can iterate throughit using

```
webeehs_result.each do |webeeh|

 # use "webeeh.webeeh_date" to access the column_name or do whatever you want with it.

end
```